# Can Turtlebot simulator be used in Groovy now?

Tags: ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

```
       Can Turtlebot simulator be used in Groovy now? It said that TurtleBot simulation is not supported in ROS Groovy!

        http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131616/can-turtlebot-simulator-be-used-in-groovy-now?/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the end of [TurtleBot](http://wiki.ros.org/action/show/Robots/TurtleBot?action=show&redirect=TurtleBot)  page, it is mentioned that "Not yet available, but in the works!"

---

Originally posted by [expelliarmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5244/expelliarmus/) with karma: 28 on 2014-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1